# iOS TabBarController: run check before entering new tab

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app which contains a UITabBarController. The last tab should only be entered when a condition is met. Currently I am checking this condition at the function `viewDidAppear`. But is it also possible to do this check every time before the tab is opened and displayed?

According to the first response I added this two files:

MainTabBarController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainTabBarController : UITabBarController

@end
```

MainTabBarController.m

```
#import "MainTabBarController.h"

@interface MainTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation MainTabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    if(indexOfTab == 2)
    {
        NSLog(@"Is it working?");
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: How can change the tint color of the selected tab ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MainTabBarController.m file,add a delegate

```
@interface MainTabBarController ()<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Then in viewDidLoad, add

```
self.delegate = self;
```

Then add a method:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:       (UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //add your check here
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is it also possible to do this check every time before the tab is
>   opened and displayed?

You need to override the `UITabBarController` `delegate` method for this :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

   if(indexofTab == yourTabIndexToMetCondition){
      // Do your stuff here 
    }

}
```

Comment: okay, I assigned a new class to the Tab Bar Controller and implemented the method you said. But it doesn't work. Do I need to change the header file too?